# C++ profiling reveals vector hotspot. How to optimize?

Tags: c++, optimization, vector, callgrind, kcachegrind

I am profiling some signal processing code using callgrind / qcachegrind involving many operations on `std::vector<float>`.

I'm getting quite a serious hotspot from the Mac OS builtin `nearbyint` function.

[image]

This seems to be called almost entirely by this vector function.

[image]

This in turn is called from many of my class member functions. To me, the `_push_back_slow_path` looks like some allocation bottleneck, but I'm not entirely sure why. At no point in the run loop am I changing the size of vectors. All that is happening, it occasionally they are copied by reference, iterated over, or the `data()` op is used to get the raw pointer for vDSP operations. For example . . .

[image]

- Why is the vDSP function a culprit for this `vector` hotspot when I am passing it a raw data pointer?
- What are the likely culprits for this hotspot?
- Why is `basic_string` appearing? The profiled lib does not use strings.
- Would switching over to `std::array` whenever possible be a wise next move?

Feel free to ask for any more info and I'll gladly edit the question.

**EDIT 1**

In response to the first answer, I am not explicitly calling `push_back` anywhere. The hotspots are occurring in seemingly bonkers places, such as this inlined log operation on a float. Could this be compiler optimization doing strange things?

[image]

Comment: Produce annotated sources. Still, `_push_back_slow_path` seems to be called by your application, even if not by your code directly.

Comment: If you try [*this*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771) you will find out what's going on.

Comment: Mike, he has 19% of time here. How "poor man's sampling" may help him? Why do you think that your method is the only possible / best method of "profiling"?

Comment: learnvst, It looks like callgrind have wrong information about lines, log10 (C) will not call `std::` (C++). Try to recompile project with debug information, less optimization level (you may want to disable inline; you should disable omit-frame-pointer).